# Footer after floating div of unknown height

Tags: html, css

I have a div of unknown height (it loads dynamically based on content). It is floating to the right. I have a footer that I want to have go after that (also a div) that would just fill the entire width of the page. However, because the other element is floating, the footer does not appear at the bottom. Is there any way to resolve this using divs?

Comment: Use `clear:both` on the footer.

Answer (score -1):

For your css styling you can use `clear:both` before the footer which will sometimes fix it.

There are a lot of different ways to do footers, if what you're doing doesn't work for you.

Since it can be a pain to get footers to stay at the bottom, I like to make my background-color of the page whatever I want my footer to be, and then have a `<div>` of all my content on top of that. Then after the content I can put whatever text I want in my footer (in another `<div>`) and it always appears like the footer is at the entire bottom.

You can get more fancy with the stylings of course. Hope this helps!

Comment: Clear: both just resets the float, it doesn't account for the extra. Doesn't particularly help. :( The app you are thinking of I don't think has a variable length of a floating div

Comment: You could try using this: http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ I've used this guy's sticky footer before. And a side note just be careful using float, because even though it's important and very useful, it messes up the flow of the document which is why 'clear:both' is useful. Let me know if this is what you're looking for. Footers can be tricky. You'll get it don't worry! :)